# Responsive gmap with always correct zoom level on specific area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a google map responsive and always have the same zoom level to focus on a a specific area, when we resize or with different resolutions.

I currently do this:

```
var map; 

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.5472,12.282715),
   zoom: 6,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
 }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
 var center = map.getCenter();
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
 map.setCenter(center);
```

This is fine but when we resize the window, the zoom level needs to change in order to always focus on the Med.

To try to solve this zoom issue, I am doing an hack but I don't think this is good:

```
if($(window).width() > 1600) {
 map.setZoom(6);
} 
if($(window).width() < 1024) {
map.setZoom(5);
} 
if($(window).width() < 800) {
 map.setZoom(4);
}
```

I read about constructing the area I want to always be in view by creating a LatLngBounds and call map.fitBounds() but I don't get it. A jsfiddle from you would be very helpful.

Here it is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tVKMn/7/

Comment: This book will answer many of your questions: http://www.barnesandnoble.com/listing/2680647336892?r=1&cm_mmca2=pla&cm_mmc=GooglePLA-_-Book_25To44-_-Q000000633-_-2680647336892

Comment: Do you mean you want the same bounds? If so, `map.getBounds()` and `map.setBounds()` are the methods your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Since I think you mean for users to see the same map no matter the size of the screen, use `map.getBounds()` to get the bounds and `map.fitBounds(LatLngBounds)` to set the bounds.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete

Comment: if you check the jfiddle I provided, you can see that if we change the screen res the map is responsive, it does get centered but the zoom level changes only according to the hack I am providing with checking the window width. I thougth I could draw a rectangle to define the area I always want to be in the viewport and when we resize the window the zooming will change according to the rectangle I told it to show